# WebAPI gives error: Class “array” does not exist

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, request

I want to send a list of statuses to my API. I send an array because it may be a lot of statuses. So my JSON looks like:

```
{  
   "statuses":[  
      "status_ok",
      "status_failed",
      "status_error",
      ....
    ]
}
```

My method for webapi looks like:

```
public function getProductsByStatuses($statuses)
    { ... code here ... }
```

but i got an error that "Class array does not exist". If in my json there is only a string not an array everything works fine. How can I fix it? Even if I add annotation array to my interface i still get this kind of error.

Comment: Could you post the part of the function where you are accessing the json array?

Comment: it was needed to add proper addotation. In this case: @param string[] $statuses instead of param array (...)